# Mysql create trigger throws error

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, insert

I've tried to create trigger for each new post
here is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertprod AFTER INSERT ON post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO attributes SET attrtext = 'sometext', post_id = NEW.id;
END;
```

I'm getting this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably just need a delimiter:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertprod AFTER INSERT ON post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO attributes SET attrtext = 'sometext', post_id = NEW.id;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

However, you are also using a non-standard form of `INSERT`.  I would suggest:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER insertprod AFTER INSERT ON post
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO attributes(attrtext, post_id)
     VALUES('sometext', NEW.id);
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT command is wrong. It should have been

```
 INSERT INTO attributes (attrtext, post_id) VALUES ('sometext', NEW.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The parser is confused by the `;` that terminates the statement inside the trigger's `BEGIN...END` block. You need to use a `DELIMITER` statement to define a new delimiter, which you can then use to end the `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.